# Exception for add area in VS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017

I press Add Area from project context menu

[image: Input box for create area]

then press Add and get this exception

[image]

What could be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. 
It was broken little bit earlier, when I configured web.config transformation. Among other things I added web.master.config file with configuration template for web.config transformation and placed it structurally above web.config file, that way:

[image]

It was achieved simply by adding **DependentUpon** element to csproj file:

```
<Content Include="Web.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <DependentUpon>Web.master.config</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

But for some reason it blocked possibility to add Areas, Controllers and etc. in my project!
After I've removed this line everything became fine again. In exception, web.master.config now have the same level as web.config:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be a corrupted assembly being referenced.

Try to clear de \bin folder of the project you tring add the area.
If still happens, you can clear the ASP.NET temp folder.

It should be in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\VERSION_OF_FRAMEWORK\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Good luck